# prevent outlook stationery from showing up in my email (Outlook 2007)

Tags: outlook-2007

There are some people in my office who insist on using cute stationery and some of it makes messages difficult to read. I really just want to read email on a white background with no distractions. Is there a way to disable stationery on incoming mail in Outlook?  (Without switching to "plain text only")

yeah, I yanked that description from [here](http://lifehacker.com/217388/call-for-help-disable-stationary-in-outlook)

but it is very accurate however I've had no luck in finding a solution.  Most solutions I see solve the problem by pushing out something to a bunch of users.

like :  [this](http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/nielsen_travis/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=6)

I don't really have the authority to do that. Not only that, that only prevents ME from setting stationery.

this has been asked before to [no avail:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567410/how-can-i-strip-stationery-from-incoming-email-in-outlook-2007-closed)

I don't have time to deal with this, so hopefully there is something I have overlooked.

**Without switching to "plain text only" I want to be able to change a setting on my computer (it can be. a reg hack, I don't care) that will prevent outlook stationery from showing up in my email**

it would also be helpful to know how to do it for Outlook 2003 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such setting/reghack exists. you would need to override the Item_Open event and change the message format from html or RTF  (if either are detected) to Plaintext. This is the only way you could reliably strip out all the formatting junk without losing the text.

that or write a custom parsing agent (which would seem to be a bit harder).

either solution involves coding an addin to handle the open event and change the message format before displaying the message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a setting, but could you copy the text and paste it in Notepad?
I use that all the time to remove obnoxious formatting.